# Non-type (reference) template parameters and linkage

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, linkage, non-type

In the following,

```
int i{3};
const int j{3};
extern const int k{3};

template <typename T, T&>
void f() {}

int main()
{
    f<int, i>();        // OK
    f<int const, j>();  // not valid template argument: 'j' has not external linkage
    f<int const, k>();  // OK
}
```

GCC gives error for the use of `j` as template parameter, while clang compiles fine.

- what is the linkage of `i`, `j`?
- why is there a difference between `const`/non-`const`?
- who is correct? GCC or clang?

Comment: Namespace scoped `const` variables have internal linkage.

Comment: It is important to note that the difference in the compilers is not whether they consider the variable to have internal/external linkage, but whether they accept that as a valid non-type template argument.

Comment: @David I got that, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Kerrek points out in the comment, namespace level `const` variables have internal linkage (unless you use the `extern` keyword).  In C++03 you cannot use the a pointer or reference of a variable with internal linkage as a non-type template argument.  That restriction was lifted in C++11.  It seems that your version of gcc is playing by the C++03 rules, while the clang compiler is using the C++11 ones.

---

14.3.2 [temp.arg.nontype] / 1

> A *template-argument* for a non-type, non-template *template-parameter* shall be one of:
>
> - [...]
> - a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an object with **static storage duration and external or internal linkage**
>   or a function with external or internal linkage, including function
>   templates and function template-ids but excluding non-static class
>   members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as & id-expression, except
>   that the & may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array
>   and shall be omitted if the corresponding template-parameter is a
>   reference; or
> - [...]

Comment: Thanks. I have tried with 4.8.1, 4.8.2 and 4.9.0 (March 2014). Same behaviour. Possible bug?

Comment: @iavr: Are you building with/without `-std=c++11`? If you build C++11 and that fails then it is a bug. Clang++ basically grew with a C++11 mindset, it (incorrectly?) does some things the C++11 way even in C++03 mode.

Comment: With either `-std=c++11` or `c++1y`. Check 4.8.2 online [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79937910c2168443).

Comment: @iavr: So that is a bug in the compiler. Added the specific quote from the standard to the answer. The quote is clear *external or **internal** linkage*

Answer (score 3):

`i` has external linkage while `j` has internal linkage. These rules are listed under *§3.5 [basic.link]*

> *4* An unnamed namespace or a namespace declared directly or indirectly within an unnamed namespace has internal linkage. **All other namespaces have external linkage. A name having namespace scope that has not been given internal linkage above has the same linkage as the enclosing namespace** if it is the name of 
>   — a variable; or
>   — ...

The global namespace has external linkage, hence `i` has external linkage as well (since it's not explicitly declared as having internal linkage).

> *3* A name having namespace scope (3.3.6) has internal linkage if it is the name of 
>   — ...
>   — a non-volatile variable that is **explicitly declared *const* or *constexpr* and neither explicitly declared *extern* nor previously declared to have external linkage**; or
>   — ...

`j` is explicitly declared `const` without being declared `extern`, hence it has internal linkage.

I believe clang is correct in this case because of *§14.3.2/1 [temp.arg.nontype]*

> A *template-argument* for a non-type, non-template *template-parameter* shall be one of:
>   — ...
>   — a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of a complete object with static storage duration and external or internal linkage ...

`j` satisfies the requirement above and should be allowed as a non-type argument.

Comment: Wouldn't `&j` designate the address, while `j` designates the variable?  Or is it being a reference variable mean that it designates the address?

Comment: @Yakk I assumed the latter. For instance, forming a reference to a `static const` class member that lacks a definition results in a linker error, the same as taking its address.

Comment: @Praetorian: Agree with a bit of handwaving, but the example is not so good. The definition is required for the `static const` class member (or integral type) because it is *odr-used*, and both binding a reference or taking the address are *odr-uses*. But yes, other than the pedantic details, to refer to an object you need to know where it lives, its address.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug, however is it known (and it is just not yet implemented, at least until gcc 4.9).

Here is the [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52036)

I expect gcc 5.0 to have that implemented, since 5.0 adds many new C++11 features.