# Before C++17, Non type template parameter of reference type cannot be bound to static global variable in gcc while it does in clang and msvc

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <std::string& N>
void printString()
{
    std::cout << N << std::endl;
}

std::string a;
static std::string b;

template void printString<a>();
template void printString<b>(); //fails


int main()
{

}
```

In C++11, why does clang compile successfully but gcc instantiation static variables with internal linkage fails? (It can be successful in gcc C++17)
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Erja3exeM)

```
<source>:14:27: error: the value of 'b' is not usable in a constant expression
   14 | template void printString<b>();
      |                           ^
<source>:11:20: note: 'b' was not declared 'constexpr'
   11 | static std::string b;
      |                    ^
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>:14:27: error: the value of 'b' is not usable in a constant expression
   14 | template void printString<b>();
      |                           ^
<source>:11:20: note: 'b' was not declared 'constexpr'
   11 | static std::string b;
      |                    ^
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

Is it a compiler implementation difference or other issues?

Comment: @fcc I don't think that is the problem. It is a compile time issue.

Comment: @user12002570 Thank you for reminding, error have been added.

Comment: @fcc why does it work on clang then like the OP mentioned?

Comment: This looks well-formed. [Pointer to an object with external linkage as a non-type template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395773/pointer-to-an-object-with-external-linkage-as-a-non-type-template-parameter)

Comment: @fcc No, your analysis is incorrect. This is valid code. Global static variables can be used as non type template argument to non-type reference parameter. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55472329/12002570) and the comments there and also other dupes. Or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27396180/12002570).

Comment: Note that GCC accepts it in C++17 mode and newer.

Comment: @user12002570 Out of your dupe links, only the first one looks related, and even it says that the code is valid starting with C++11, while GCC rejects it in C++11 mode. I'm tempted to reopen this.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, the code is valid from C++11. The difference is that from c+11, internal linkage is allowed. This was not the case before C++11. Gcc seems to have a bug.

Comment: Thanks, @user12002570. I followed your second link, and yes, I am wrong.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've added 2 another [dupes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479015/non-type-reference-template-parameters-and-linkage) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763443/template-non-type-argument-c11-restriction-for-string-literals)